# How can I set the value of an array element to true for an element with another value?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects named `test`.

Using modern browsers is there an easy way for me to find an element in that array with a `testId` set to 99 and set that element's `current` 
field to true?

If possible I would like to avoid something like a for each loop but I am not sure what can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var test = [ {"testId" : 99, "current" : false }, {"testId" : 10, "current" : false }];

test.forEach(function(r) {
    if (r.testId == 99) {
        r.current = true;
    }
});
```

Not sure why you want to avoid the loop, and also not clear from your question if you want to do it for all elements that satisfy the condition (which the above code currently does) or break after the first one.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5ty8dck/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var found = test.filter(function( obj ) {
  return obj.testId == 99;
})[0];
if (found) found.current = true;
```